# Estoy buscando un algoritmo de machine learning para planificar rutas óptimas de multiples camiones recolectores

Tags: python, go, machine-learning

Mi dataset tiene las siguientes columnas:

1. Latitud
2. Longitud
3. Nombre del nodo
4. Estado del nodo (lleno / vacío)
5. Dirección
6. Ciudad

El objetivo es trazar una ruta óptima para cada vehículo considerando solo los nodos con estado "lleno".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que buscas resolver se conoce como el [problema del viajante](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problema_del_viajante), el cual pertenece al grupo de [np-completo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-completo),
ya que el esfuerzo por resolver un problema dado de forma eficiente puede variar en gran medida, se busca una solución cercana y fácil de computar en un problema de heurística

Una definición aceptada puede ser **"Un proceso que puede resolver un problema
dado, pero que no ofrece ninguna garantía de que lo hará, se llama una heurística para ese problema"**

Características de los métodos heurísticos

- No garantiza una solución, aunque exista
- Si encuentra una solución, no valida que sea la más optima
- En algunas ocasiones encontraran solución en un corto tiempo

Se suele generar un conjunto de resultados y ordenarlos, de esta manera la ruta mas corta, o la solución mas optima, quedara en primer lugar

para su caso en particular tendrá que añadir la lógica de negocio aparte y ahí aplicar quizás otras ideas sobre machine learning

Existen algunos algoritmos propuestos que resuelven el problema

- [Algoritmos genéticos](https://www.cs.us.es/cursos/ia1-2011/trabajos/propuesta-gen-tsp.html#:%7E:text=En%20el%20problema%20del%20viajante,de%20la%20lista%20de%20ciudades.)
- [Algoritmo de Dijkstra](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_de_Dijkstra)
- [Algoritmo de la colonia de hormigas](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_de_la_colonia_de_hormigas)

Comment: El OP busca solucionar una solución generada por machine learning, no la codificación de una heurística.

Comment: Según entiendo el enfoque heurístico es característica de las ia, dentro del ámbito de soluciones parciales, ahora depende de que enfoque utilizar para resolver el problema, uno clásico o uno en ia, aunque de esto ultimo no estoy tan seguro

Comment: machine learning es una de varias técnicas usadas en IA. Por ejemplo, para ganar en "Asteroid", la heurística es dejar un sólo trozo de asteroide volando y esperar a que aparezcan los ovnis para destruirlos y acumular puntaje. Es algo que se puede codificar sin requerir machine learning.